# Access google connections using google people API

Tags: google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api, passport-google-oauth

I would like to fetch all the google private connections of a user signed in from my app.
I've enabled the Google People and the Google Plus API's. I set up the credentials API key, client id & client secret. The url with which I'm trying to fetch the users connections is

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?fields=connections&key=api_key&access_token=access_token
```

Also, I'm using the library **passport-google-oauth**, to get the users access_token. Is there anything that I'm missing in the above URL.

My google auth code is

```
    // send to google to do the authentication
    // profile gets us their basic information including their name
    // email gets their emails
    app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']
    }));

    // the callback after google has authenticated the user
    app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned what error you are getting but by looking at the url you are using I can tell you a few things.

[people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) access private user data.  So for one you don't need to add Key that is just used for accessing public data.  However having both should not result in any error message.

I have tested the request you are sending and it does work however this request requires that you have authenticated with at least one of the [connections scopes](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#connection-scopes).

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts  Requests that your app be
>   given read and write access to the contacts in the authenticated
>   user’s Google Contacts.
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly Requests that your
>   app be given read access to the contacts in the authenticated user’s
>   Google Contacts.

If you have not then you will get a no access error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I got the API key thing. But with the access_token I pass, I get the following error : **Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token google people api**. I'm using the package google-passport-oauth to get the user token & google-api-nodejs-client to access people API for google

Comment: @ParthVyas if you have got the access token, try using it as header of your request (perhaps `Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken`)

Comment: @BNK you don't need to do that by tacking &access_token= on the end of the request you are doing the same thing.

Comment: @ParthVyas please post your auth code I think there is something wrong with your access token generation

Comment: @DaImTo I've updated the question with the auth code, please have a look!

Comment: @ParthVyas I have not tried the `passport-google-oauth` library, however according to https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#retrieve-authorization-code, IMO, you should have the authorization code to get an access token

Comment: Yes @BNK I'll try the **google-api-nodejs-client** now & check if the token is considered valid or not

Comment: @ParthVyas I am not a node dev but where are you adding the client id and client secret?  https://c9.io/barberboy/passport-google-oauth2-example